# Share iPad internet connection to PC over USB

Tags: ipad, network, usb, internet

Can I use my iPad to connect to my PC over USB and receive internet? My iPad has Internet but at the moment my PC doesn't and I don't have a wireless router yet.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed on Super User:
[How to connect iPhone's internet to Windows PC via USB cable?](https://superuser.com/a/729005/219569):

> 1. Install latest iTunes on Windows PC
> 2. iPhone Settings -> Mobile -> Personal Hotpsot -> ON
> 3. Select "USB Cable" on window that pops up
> 4. Connect iPhone to Windows PC
>
> The latest version of iTunes needs to be installed, because that will install the drivers required for Windows to see the iPhone as a modem and use it to bridge a connection to the internet.

Comment: I burned my entire month's phone data allowance in 15 minutes the one & only time I did that - beware.